# Data visualization using Drupal-8 Views, Flipped Table and Charts API?

Tags: charts, data-visualization, drupal-8, drupal-views, drupal-views-relationship

I have created a simple form to collect 15 inputs. I installed Flipped Table to flip the table from row to column format and created a new view to display the flipped table using rendered entity.

Then I added a chart attachment to the Master Flipped Table page. The main label is Submission ID and the data fields are the 15 categories. The pie chart is not showing at all. I seem to be stuck in bridging the data from the fields to the pie chart. Any direction will be most helpful.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the Charts module, in this case I would recommend adding a regular attachment, and then setting the display settings to Chart (Chart attachment is really intended as a second series on an existing chart). Also, please be sure to inspect element and look at the console for any JS errors...it's possible your charting library was not installed properly, and that would give you a good indication.

Comment: That was the problem, the charting library was not installed correctly. Thank you